# Python requests scraping images get corrupt

Tags: python, python-requests, python-imaging-library

referring the same question in [Scraped images is corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533569/scraped-images-is-corrupt)

In my case
Trying to scrape images from site with

[image]

There are 100 images, First 67 Images saved fine as .jpg, from 68 all the images are corrupted, windows says doesn't support this file format

As per other stackoverflow question I dont have the data-src, content is shown in above image

request script is

```
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url, headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36',
        'Referer' : url
    })
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    image_info = []
    imagePrefix = url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1:][0] + "_"
    imgNo = 0
    for item in soup.find_all('img'):
      imageID = imagePrefix + str(imgNo)   
      image_info.append((item["src"], imageID))
      imgNo = imgNo + 1
    folder_name = url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1:][0]
    df = pd.DataFrame(image_info, columns =['imageURL', 'imageID'])
    df['category'] = folder_name
    df_full = df_full.append(df)
    parent_dir = "C:/data/images/"
    path = os.path.join(parent_dir, folder_name)
    os.mkdir(path)
    for i in range(0, len(image_info)):
        download_image(image_info[i], folder_name)
```

How this issue can be fixed

Comment: Is the file extension available? If not try to use png or jpeg

Comment: no, its not available, but those 67 images saved fine as image0.jpg and so on

Comment: Tried response.content, thats also not working

Comment: What’s an example of `url`?

Comment: Have you printed the URLs to a separate file to see if you can fetch them with `wget` or `curl`?

Comment: =w1280 at the end of google media urls, is usually referring to a thumbnail of original resource. As per google docs, it supports BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, WebP, and SVG as the formats. Try any of this formats and see if it works.